# How to load an array/list of string values in Spinner excluding one value?

Tags: android, spinner

I need to create two Spinners (both displaying a list of locations) with the following rules:

Let's say I have a universal set of locations as under:

- **India, Japan, China, South Korea, Sri Lanka, Nepal** [Locations on Route-1]
- **USA, Mexico, Canada, Jamaica** [Locations on Route-2]
- **Germany, France, Russia, Spain, Italy** [Locations on Route-3]
- **Brazil, Argentina, Chile** [Locations on Route-4]

Consider that the locations in these 4 lists lie along 4 unique routes as listed above.

Now, **I want to populate all the locations in the universal set in Spinner-1 (i.e. countries on all the 4 routes)**, which will serve as a "From" location selector.

Once a location is selected from Spinner-1, I want to populate Spinner-2 (which serves as a "To" location selector) only with those locations which appear on the specific route on which the selected location lies. Also, I want to exclude the selected location from Spinner-1 from displaying in Spinner-2.

For eg., if Mexico is selected from Spinner-1, Spinner-2 should display USA, Canada, Jamaica...

What is the best mechanism to program this requirement?

Comment: What does spinner 1 contains ? all the countries you mentioned above or one single Route ?

Comment: Spinner-1 will contain all the countries mentioned along all routes...

Answer (score 1):

**OK I have done it now, The Main Logic is**

1. Create an array and adapter for first spinner.
2. Inside the `onItemSelectedListener` method of first spinner, remove the selected element and set adapter to second spinner.

**Let's have a look**

You have an `ArrayList` of countries like this

```
final ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
    countries.add("India");
    countries.add("Japan");
    countries.add("China");
    countries.add("South Korea");
    countries.add("Nepal");
```

**And you have two spinner (spinner & spinner2)**

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1);
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner2); //It is final because it was accessed within inner class but if you don't want so then declare it as class level variable
```

You made an Adapter for `spinner` first

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

And inside onItemSelected of `spinner` remove the selected element from array and set adapter to second `spinner` that is `spinner2`

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 ArrayList<String> tempCounties = (ArrayList<String>) countries.clone();

               tempCounties.remove(position);
               ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tempCounties);
               spinnerArrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               spinner2.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the statement 'countries.remove(position);' modify the original countries array?

Comment: But doesn't this code again display countries on a different route in Spinner-2? Where are we applying the filtering logic for preparing Spinner-2?

Comment: If you want to prevent that you can make a temporary variable `ArrayList<String> tempCounties = countries;`

Comment: I think we need to build separate lists for each route & then have a switch-case kind of logic to populate Spinner-2 adapter suitably with the appropriate route array....

Comment: Yah surely you can if it is comfortable. But the main logic is this. You can assign what to put and what not to inside the `onOptionItemSelected.`

Comment: @AdityaRaj Hi bro, Have you solved it ? I finally managed to solve this, If in case of not done, then I updated my all answer, you can easily copy and paste. All issues are gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String[] regionsArray;
List<String> regions;
Spinner spinner;

regionsArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Country_array);
regions=new ArrayList<String>();
regions = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(regionsArray));

/* selected item will look like a spinner set from XML */
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, regions);

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


/* Your ARRAY Defined in xml file */
<string-array name="Country_array">
  <item>India</item>
  <item>Japan</item>
  <item>China</item>
</string-array>
```